# How to filter a custom attribute in customer grid?

Tags: magento2.3, attributes, grid

I've created a custom customer attribute (`postive_cust_id`) and got it to appear in the admin customer grid (following the instructions of this guide: https://magentodeveloper.in/add-custom-attribute-to-customer-magento2.html)

To whit, this is now an attribute in the `customer_eav_varchar` table. When I try to filter the customer grid using this attribute specifically (i.e. clicking 'Filter' and entering a value in the attribute text field) I get "Something has gone wrong" modal popup. When I search in my logs I see this message:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'postive_cust_id' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
>   `customer_grid_flat` AS `main_table` WHERE (`postive_cust_id` LIKE
>   '%12675%')

How do I hook or extend the Customer Grid Filter to do a join for my attribute? e.g.

> SELECT count(*) FROM `customer_grid_flat` AS `main_table`
>
> INNER JOIN customer_entity_varchar cet ON cet.entity_id = main_table.entity_id
>
> WHERE cet.attribute_id = 169 AND (cet.value LIKE '%12675%')

I've hard coded the attribute id (169) but if this could do a number of inner joins based on the attribute code that would be preferred.